# RStudio IDE has bad resolution

Tags: debian, rstudio

Why is the RStudio IDE looking in such a bad quality and how can I make it look better? Characters and options are fuzzy and with low bright. Here is a picture of my IDE (for some reason, the picture looks much better than reality):
[image: rstudio ide picture with dark theme]

I'm using RStudio in a debian 11 virtual machine, runing within a chromebook. The specs of my hardware are:

- Processor: Pentium N5000
- RAM: 4GB
- OS: Chrome OS
- VM: Debian 11